# Why does guard start spork both for rspec and cucumber even if I wanted to start it only for rspec using groups?

Tags: rspec, cucumber, spork, guard

In my Gemfile...

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara', "1.1.2"
  gem 'database_cleaner', "0.7.0"

  gem 'cucumber', "1.1.2"
  gem 'cucumber-rails', "1.2.0"

  gem 'rspec-rails', "2.7.0"

  gem 'spork', "0.9.0.rc9"

  gem 'launchy' #launches the page

  gem 'guard-spork', "0.3.1"
  gem 'guard-rspec', "0.5.4"
  gem 'guard-cucumber', "0.7.4"

  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

My Guardfile have two groups (:specs and :features).

```
group :specs do

  guard :spork, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
    watch('config/application.rb')
    watch('config/environment.rb')
    watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
    watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
    watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
  end

  guard :rspec, :version => 2 do
    watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
    watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # # Rails example
    watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
    watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
    watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
    watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
    watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')                        { "spec" }
    watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
    watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
    # Capybara request specs
    watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  end

end

group :features do

  guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
    watch('config/application.rb')
    watch('config/environment.rb')
    watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
    watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
    watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
  end

  guard 'cucumber' do
    watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
    watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
    watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
  end

end
```

When I try to run the :specs group, I would expect guard to run Spork for Rspec only.

```
guard -g specs start
```

However, I can see from the output that guard runs Spork both for Rspec and Cucumber.

```
~/current[master]% guard -g specs start
WARNING: You are using Guard outside of Bundler, this is dangerous and may not work. Using `bundle exec guard` is safer.
Guard could not detect any of the supported notification libraries.
Guard is now watching at '/Users/rupert/Desktop/cws-rails'
Starting Spork for RSpec & Cucumber 
Using RSpec
Using Cucumber
Preloading Rails environment
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8990!
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Spork server for RSpec & Cucumber successfully started
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
```

Is there any config file for SPORK or guard that I might have missed?

UPDATE:

1. Remove guard-cucumber
2. Remove or Rename features folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must disable Cucumber in Spork in the RSpec group and the other way around:

```
specs :specs    
  guard :spork, :cucumber => false do
    # ...
  end
end

specs :features    
  guard 'spork', :rspec => false do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but I also stumbled over this problem right now and figured it out:

I had a `features` subdirectory within my project with one file:
`features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb`

Looking up the commits I realized that this was added from rails_apps_composer: testing framework.

So:

Removing the subdirectory `features` prevents `spork` from trying to use cucumber.